# What will happen if I join power-play faction but I have ships stored in the enemy territory?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I was wondering what will happen if I have a ship stored in a space station that is controlled by the opposite faction. 
I've read somewhere that once you join the faction you will be targeted in the territory of other factions.

Will I be able dock at a station exploited by another faction and if so would the local authority attack me?

Comment: I'm unable to test because I only roll with one ship, but I do know that other factions can be unfriendly or hostile without actually attacking you for no reason. You can still dock in another faction's controlled system, and should be able to use all the facilities at a station AFAIK.

Comment: If the local authority or the faction that is exploiting the system is hostile towards you, then I believe there is a chance they will attack on site.  I think it is more of an issue, though, with whichever local faction controls the station that the ships are in.  Personally, I would consider moving them to a friendlier location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically nothing important happens.

When you're in "hostile" territory (system controlled or exploited by a different power), you might be interdicted and attacked by that power's special PowerPlay NPCs. You also might be attacked by actual players (but much less likely in exploited systems).

When you're in your own power's territory, you might be interdicted and attacked by every other power's special PowerPlay NPCs. You also might be attacked by actual players who are undermining your power.

The actual "system authority" ships and stations don't care about PowerPlay stuff. It's only the PowerPlay NPCs that care about it.

If you undermine in a system, you'll become wanted there. But, even when you're wanted in a system, you can dock in the stations (as long as you do it fast enough to avoid scans).

So, really, the only difference is the names on the PowerPlay ships that attack you...

Comment: And if i was doing lot of stuff for the Federation (to get to SOL once, and now i join ADL will i loose the reputation for the Federation?)

Comment: Powerplay and major factions are only loosely connected. You can be pledged to an imperial power and still stay allied or friendly with the federation and alliance.